# Eclipse Output Folders

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, jakarta-ee

With following structure, how can I make Eclipse build the WAR file correctly?

I need following folders to go into following output folders:

**mail/src** into **mail/war/WEB-INF/classes**

**mail/www** into **mail/war/**

I have tried setting the Output folders in Eclipse, but that doesn't result in anything but Eclipse magically deleting all WEB-INF content without telling me!

http://clausjoergensen.dk/media/files/gwt-pro-stru.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't typically create my GWT projects using the "Web Application Project" wizard as I don't like having to remove all default servlets and classes. I usually create them as "Dynamic Web Projects" which will allow you to export as a WAR among other things.

1. Create a new "Dynamic Web Project" and complete the first step of the wizard based off you project preferences.
2. Select Next > Next to get you to the "Web Module" configuration settings.
3. Enter your context root and change your "Content Directory" to "war" and click "Finish"

This will create you just a basic web project you will next need to enable GWT on this project and add you base configurations.

1. Open your project Properties and goto "Google" > "Web Toolkit" and check "Use Google Web Toolkit" Select "Ok" to close this dialog box.
2. Select "File" > "New" > "Other" to open the new "New" dialog box. Select "Google Web Toolkit" folder then select "Module" then "Next"
3. Enter your package info and module name. This will create you your ModuleName.gwt.xml file in the package you entered. It will also create a empty your.package.name.client for you.
4. Select "File" > "New" > "Other" again and this time select "Entry Point Class." In the wizard that opens confirm that Module, Package, and Source are correct. Enter the "Name" of the Entry point, This would typically be your module name. Then select "Finish"
5. One more time select "File" > "New" > "Other" and select "HTML Page." Confirm that "Path" is  pointing to "war" and "Modules" displays your module. Enter the "FileName" this can be anything you want i.e. index.html, index.jsp, module.html

At this point you have a Dynamic Web Project that is fully GWT enabled. To get the run setting set up properly just select "Run" from the menu and select "Run" again. Then select "Web Application" from the dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna use GWT on eclipse, you should use the [Google Plugin for Eclipse](http://code.google.com/intl/fr-FR/eclipse/)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a small ant build script. Ant is already integrated in eclipse, just drop a build.xml file in the root directory and either build manually or add an Ant builder to the project.

Answer (score 0):

Your www folder shouldn't be a source folder (with the small package icon). It should be a regular folder and reside at mail/war/www.

As for mail/src, just have a look at the build path of the project and make sure that the output folder is set to mail/war/WEB-INF/classes.

Comment: Dynamic content (source code) inside the WAR seems rather strange to me. Isn't it meant to present a OUTPUT folder? That's why I'd like to move it away from the WAR, to get better source control options!

Comment: You can make it a source folder and configure individual output folders for each source folder, but that is not how WTP intended it. Are you using WTP? If so, just put your jsps, images, css etc. under the www folder (the default name is WebContent if you use the project wizard)

Answer (score 0):

1. You mail project is Java project. To build war you need `Dynamic Web Project`
2. In Web project that you will create, set `mail/war as a content directory` (instead of default `WebContent`).
3. Refactor->Move `mail/www` directory to `mail/war/www`
4. When you export WAR, make sure you include source code.

Now if you `export WAR`, it will contain what you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

Right, so the solution was to move WEB-INF into /www/ and make a WEB-INF/classes/ folder containing a dummy file.

Without the dummy file Eclipse wouldn't build, and complain about the classes folder didn't exist.