# Getting html input value with request.getParameter() / getAttribute() returns null

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I'm writing a web project and I need to pass information to and from my mySQL database. I have java code that works (i.e shows data from database , no problem there) and javascript that is supposed to handle the information.
I have a form (name, last name and so on) and I need to check if the name , last name already exist in the database.
My problem is passing the text from the `<input>` field where the user writes to the java method.

My input fields are in a form, the checking function is set "oninput" so every key stroke it checks .The input fields:

```
First name: <input class="inName" type="text" id="FirstName" name="FirstName" oninput="checkExist()"/><span id="info1" class="info"></span><br>
        Last name: <input class="inLName" type="text" id="LastName" name="LastName" oninput="checkExist()"/><span id="info2" class="info"></span><br>
```

the check function:

```
function checkExist(){


    <%
    MyConnection myCon = MyConnection.getConnection();
    String fName = (String)request.getParameter("FirstName");
    String lName = (String)request.getParameter("LastName");

    String result = myCon.userExist(fName, lName);

    %>

    var res = "<%=result%>"

    alert(res);
}
```

the alert indicates that the java function works properly.
everything is fine except the request.getParameter() returns null instead of the input text.

I tried :

1. getAttribute
2. putting .toString() at the end
3. getElementByid() and try to pass it to the function (which does not work)

and so on and so forth.
I can't seem to get it to work!
Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Am wondering how can you write script-let code into the javascript function which gets called and run at client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi so thanks everyone for answering!!!!
I did something similar to the answers provided with a few changes as it seems I had more problems in my project than initially suggested:

1.I created a new Dynamic web project (the first one was static) as shown here:

[Eclipse Output Folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077345/eclipse-output-folders)

(I didn't bother with the google toolkit)

2.I copied all the contents of the old project into the new dynamic project (webcontent into war , java resources into java resources and so on) and added the jar of the jdbc to both java and WEB-INF lib folders and added the jar in the java build path libraries.(at first I didn't have a lib folder in WEB-INF but I created one and added the jar there- very important because otherwise -no jdbc connection)

3.I set the java build path default output folder to project/war/WEB-INF/classes

4.I changed the view to "navigator" (window->show view->navigator) in order to see the default output folder and checked I have my java classes compiled in the classes folder

as for the code-
I now have a java class called "MyConnection" that opens the jdbc connection and has methods that send and receive data from the database.

I have a checkUser.jsp that receives variables from ajax and sends them to the MyConnection methods:

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page import="javafiles.MyConnection"%>


<%

String fName = (String)request.getParameter("fname");
String lName = (String)request.getParameter("lname");

String result = MyConnection.userExist(fName, lName);
response.getWriter().flush();
response.getWriter().write(result);

%>
```

and I have an ajax function that gets the variables from the input fields and sends them to the checkUser:

```
<script>
function checkExist(){

    $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "checkUser.jsp",
          data: {'fname':$("#FirstName").val(),'lname':$("#LastName").val()},
          success: function(data){
              console.log(data);
             var exist=data[0];



                //Query the jQuery object for the values

            if(exist>0){
                alert("user already exists!")
            }
          },
          dataType: "text"
        });

}

</script>
```

The function is called from the onchange attribute of the input:

```
First name: <input class="inName" type="text" id="FirstName" name="FirstName" onchange="checkExist()"/><span id="info1" class="info"></span><br>
```

And that's it !
I know it's a long answer but it contains a few things I struggled with and wish to share with future fellow coders.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

**Why you are getting null:**
When the main page html code is generated on server side there are no request parameters with these names and therefore you get null. The code which you mentioned checks for parameters when generating the main page html on server side(code within these <% %> tags). And as per your requirement these parameters should be null here. And These parameters should be checked in a separate request and not in this one.

Actually you intend to call checkExists when user inputs something on client side. But the code within these <% %> tags will be already processed 
on server side. when the page loads on the browser, your var res will be "" and alert code will get executed.

Following is what you will get when you do view page source instead of what you intended:

```
function checkExist(){
var res = ""
alert(res);
```

}

**Solution:**
You need to create another http api say /checkNameExists and  from client side use ajax function to call this http api passing the required form parameters and then process the response accordingly.

Do the following : 
1. remove the code within the tag <% .. %> and also "var res" line
2. create http api requests checkFirstNameExists which takes a parameter firstName
3. create another http api checkLastNameExists(to keep things simple create another or change as required) which takes parameter lastName.
4. Instead of checkExists,create checkFirstNameExists and checkLastNameExists and call appropriately for input boxes
5. Inside checkFirstNameExists use ajax (may be using jQuery. [Example](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_post)) to call http api checkFirstNameExists http api and process the output as desired.
6. Similarly for checkLastNameExists

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that thoose parameters you are looking for in the request, are not yet in that request. This is because you are writting your java code in the same jsp (client side) so the request is the "previous one", i mean until, you submit your form, those parameters wont be accesible from client side. 
you probably will be able to solve this if you create a javascript function that is fired with the onChange event of the inputs happens. Then you get the value and pass it to your function.